# Facebook for Android error on getting gender of user

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Some users are getting a force close when signing up with Facebook in our app. We received this stacktrace on the lines below:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=1
at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:588)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1475)
at com.yolify.android.Activity_Splash$7.onCompleted(Activity_Splash.java:483)
at com.facebook.Request$1.onCompleted(Request.java:281)
at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1666)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code:**

```
String gender = user.getProperty("gender") == null ?  "" :  user.getProperty("gender").toString();
String Gender = gender == null ? "" : gender.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)+gender.substring(1);
```

The force close happens on the second line of the code. Since that happens in about 1 in 100 signups, we can't reproduce the issue. If the gender is not null then what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If the gender is not null then what is it?" : it probably is null but you turn it into an empty string. Then an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` comes from trying to do substring(1) on that empty string.

The problem is the way you have used two back-to-back ternary operations.

The first ternary operation

```
String gender = user.getProperty("gender") == null ? "" : user.getProperty("gender").toString()
```

Is basically saying

```
if(user.getProperty("gender") == null){
    gender="";
}
else{
    gender=user.getProperty("gender").toString();
}
```

So far so good.
The second ternary operation (This is where it gets confusing. I dont know why you wrote 'String Gender'; I think you should replace with 'gender')

```
String Gender = gender == null ? "" : gender.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)+gender.substring(1)
```

Is basically saying

```
if(gender == null){
    gender = ""; //gender instead of String Gender
}
else{
    gender = gender.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH) + substring(1)
}
```

Note that the first condition is always false because of the first ternary operation. Basically the second ternary operation will ALWAYS throw that IndexOutOfBoundsException in the event someone used a facebook account with null gender because your first ternary operation makes an empty string and your second ternary operation is trying to get a substring of that empty string. An easy way to test this is to create a new fb account and not fill in the gender and then sign into your app.

The fix: I tend to avoid ternary operations like the plague because even though they saves lines of code, its easy to get confused especially when you have two back to back that deal with the same variables. I would replace the 2nd ternary operation with

```
if(gender != "") { // Gender exists
    gender = gender.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
}
else{
    // gender us "" so do whatever
}
```

Thats the "most correct way" I could think of handling this. You could also try just getting rid of the +substring(1) in the second ternary operation and that would get rid of the error but thats not what I recommend.